# Avoid multiple page redirects Gatsby http -> https

Tags: redirect, pagespeed, http-redirect

In https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights I see that my speed is really delayed because of the error above.
I tried to solve it by adding package to gatsby-config.js, but it doesn't work. In my site-config.js siteUrl: `https://mysite.co`. How can I solve it?

```
{
      resolve: 'gatsby-plugin-htaccess',
      options: {
        RewriteBase: '/custom/',
        https: true,
        SymLinksIfOwnerMatch: true,
        host: 'mysite.co',
        redirect: [
          'RewriteRule ^not-existing-url/?$ /existing-url [R=301,L,NE]',
          {
            from: 'http:mysite.co',
            to: 'https:mysite.co',
          },
        ],
      },
    },
```

[image]

Comment: redirects are configurate on the server. If you use apache then you probably have `.htaccess` file where you write it. if you use nginx then maybe under `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

Answer (score 0):

need to add `https` gatsby-config.js

```
module.exports = {
  siteMetadata: {
    siteUrl: `https:mysite.co`
  },
```